# Populate textboxes when displayed to user

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF page with a lot of textboxes on it and all of them have to be loaded from xml data (this takes a bit too long).

```
var tRange = new TextRange(tbox.Document.ContentStart, tbox.Document.ContentEnd); 
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(value))
{
    tRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Xaml); 
}
```

Is there a way to load the content of the texboxes as they are displayed to the user?
They are all in a ScrollView, but only a few of them are visible at any time.

As a note: I tried to do the loading in a Loaded event and in the OnRender event of my textbox, but in both cases the method was called for all of the items on the page, not just the visible ones.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note here, is that you are loading the information sequentially. Because of that, the UI has no time to render between each load of the `TextBox`. As such, *all* of the `TextBox` controls are displayed with the loaded information once the sequential process has been completed.

If you want to display the loaded information in the `TextBox` controls incrementally, it may be worth running the loading process on a separate thread or [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) ([tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). This way, when you finish loading some information for a `TextBox`, you can call back to the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) thread and update the `TextBox`. Then, WPF will have chance to render the information while you are continuing the laborious loading process in the background (it also makes for a nicer user experience, rather than getting the appearance of a frozen application).

Comment: But the problem is the tRange.Load, this has to be done in the Gui Thread since it updates the textbox, so I don't know what I could do in a Backgroundworker. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @RobotMess I see your problem. In that case, it is all internalized within the `TextRange` class. In that case, it might be worth looking into using WPF binding with a `BackgroundWorker` and controlling the load process yourself.

Comment: I have tried to follow you sugestion, but I cannot firure out mean by: WPF binding with a BackgroundWorker

Comment: @RobotMess Look into [WPF Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and the two links I've given for the `BackgroundWorker` in my post. If you read through those links you should get enough of an understanding to decide whether my suggestion is a feasible solution. If you get stuck on the understanding of the concepts or implementation, let me know.

Comment: It's a bit late, but I looked into it, the only method of making it work with a BackgroundWorker is to have another GUI thread. The only problem is that object cannot simply be passed from one GUI thread to another, I would have to serialize the processed items and reload them in my first GUI Thread. This was a lot of work, and the performance benefit was minimal.

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood what was going on in your example - I can see that you are deferring the loading of the data to the `TextRange` control, which will be operating on the UI thread - hence your issue. If that is the case, it might be worth looking into an alternative to the `TextRange` control - perhaps something third party or just something you have more control over.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a background worker, That way the texboxes will keep getting filled up in the backgroud, and the ui will stay responsive.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)

{

    //Fill Textboxes

};



worker.RunWorkerAsync("XMLPATH");
```

Comment: The problem is the tRange.Load this has to be done in the Gui Thread since it updates the textbox.